# How do I execute a Javascript every 10 minutes in a HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I use the google Maps API on my Website. I show a route, the distance and the duration of the route. Therefore I have the following code:

```
 <script>
 function initMap() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom: 5,});
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
draggable: false,
map: map,
panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')});
directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
});
displayRoute('Zeiskamer Straße 1, 76756 Bellheim', 'Voelklingen', directionsService, directionsDisplay);
}


function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
service.route({
origin: origin,
destination: destination,
travelMode: 'DRIVING',
avoidTolls: true,
drivingOptions: {
  departureTime: new Date(Date.now() + 100),
  trafficModel: 'optimistic'
                 },
}, 
function(response, status) {
if (status === 'OK') {
  display.setDirections(response);
} else {
  alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
}
});
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
var total = 0;
var myroute = result.routes[0];

total = "Die Entfernung beträgt: <b>" +myroute.legs[0].distance.text     +"</b>";
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + "<br>"+ "Die voraussichtliche Fahrzeit beträgt: <b>" +      myroute.legs[0].duration_in_traffic.text  + "</b>" + seconds;


}


</script>
<script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I want that the`duration_in_traffic` is updated every 10min. But I am not sure how to execute a function with a parameter every 10 min.
How can I do that?

Comment: you can use `setInterval(function() {},
10*60*1000)`

Comment: here the function is function that you want to call at regular interval of 10 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up a timer which will call the function every ten minutes:

```
function initMap() {
  ...
  // Call initially
  displayRoute('Zeiskamer Straße 1, 76756 Bellheim', 'Voelklingen', directionsService, directionsDisplay);

  // And then call it again every 10 minutes
  setInterval(function() {
    displayRoute('Zeiskamer Straße 1, 76756 Bellheim', 'Voelklingen', directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
  // ^ 10 minutes in ms
}
```

For convenience, you can wrap the `displayRoute` in another function:

```
function initMap() {
  ...
  var displayRouteHandler = function () {
     displayRoute('Zeiskamer Straße 1, 76756 Bellheim', 'Voelklingen', directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  };
  // Call initially
  displayRouteHandler();

  // And then call it again every 10 minutes
  setInterval(displayRouteHandler, 10 * 60 * 1000);
  // ^ 10 minutes in ms
}
```

This is better because you don't have repetitive code.

Comment: Thank you for the best answer!!

Answer (score 2):

Use setInterval to do a task on repeated intervals

```js
setInterval( function() { showAlert('this'); }, 10*60*1000 );

function showAlert(text){
   alert("called "+text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout() like this:

```js
function one() {
    console.log(+new Date());
    setTimeout(function() {
      one();
    }, 1000)
}

one();
```

every second change the value；
you can use setTimeout(callback, 10 * 60 * 1000) to second callback every 10 min

Comment: That seems an awkward workaround. Why not just `setInterval()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval to perform something again and again after certain time.

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("test");
},3000);
```

This logs "test" after every 3 seconds.